# Setting a Style from codebehind crashes the app

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

I have this Page:

```
<Page
    x:Class="My.FilesPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:My"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
    xmlns:viewmodel="using:My.ViewModel" xmlns:controls="using:Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls"
    d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=viewmodel:FilesPageViewModel}"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Page.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="ListView" x:Name="ListStyle">
            <Setter Target="ItemContainerStyle">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                    </Style>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Target="ItemTemplate">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <RelativePanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Padding="0, 16">
                            <Image RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel="True" 
                                                   Source="Assets/Files.png" 
                                                   Width="32" Margin="16, 0"
                                                   Name="FileThumb"/>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" RelativePanel.RightOf="FileThumb">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ModifiedDate}"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                            <Button RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel="True" Background="Transparent">
                                <Image Source="Assets/icon_Less.png" Width="16" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                            </Button>
                        </RelativePanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="ListView" x:Name="GridStyle">
            <Setter Target="ItemsPanel">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <controls:WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Target="ItemTemplate">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Width="125" >
                            <Image Source="Assets/Files.png" Width="115"/>
                            <RelativePanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel="True" MaxWidth="96" TextWrapping="Wrap" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"/>
                                <Button Background="Transparent" RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel="True">
                                    <Image Source="Assets/icon_Less.png" Width="16" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                </Button>
                            </RelativePanel>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Page.Resources>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
            <ToggleButton Name="ViewStyleToggle"
                          IsChecked="False" Background="Transparent"
                          Checked="EnableGridStyle" Unchecked="EnableListStyle"
                          Content="Toggle"/>                
        <ListView Name="FileListView" ItemsSource="{Binding Files}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                  Style="{StaticResource ListStyle}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Page>
```

And I set the Style of the ListView when the user presses the button, from this code:

```
namespace My
{
    public sealed partial class FilesPage : Page
    {
        public FilesPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void EnableGridStyle(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            FileListView.Style = (Style)Resources["GridStyle"];
        }
        public void EnableListStyle(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            FileListView.Style = (Style)Resources["ListStyle"];
        }
    }
}
```

Changing the style like this crashes the application with no meaningful stack trace. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default ItemsPanel template used by ListView is `ItemsStackPanel`, it is VirtualizingStackPanel. For higher performance, please use the ItemsPanel instead of the `WrapPanel` that you used as the ItemsPanel template for the **GridStyle**, and set its `Orientation property` to Horizontal.

Since you want the  get the desired wrapping behavior, you could use the `ItemsWrapGrid` as the ItemsPaneltempalte to achieve this effect, which is also VirtualizingStackPanel.

At the same time, WrapPanel can not do UI virtualization, which might cause problems with the rendering, etc. So you could refer to the following code to change **GridStyle**.

```
<Style TargetType="ListView" x:Key="GridStyle">
            <Setter Target="ItemsPanel">
                <Setter.Value>
                  <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <ItemsWrapGrid Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                  </ItemsPanelTemplate>   
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
……
</Style>
```

**Note that** you need to use the **Key** of style not Name to change the style(such as `x:Key="GridStyle"`).

Comment: In order to get the desired wrapping behavior I had to use ItemsWrapGrid, but your answer pointed me to it. If you edit that in I'll accept the answer.

Comment: @marczellm Yes, you could also use the ItemsWrapGrid, that also works. That is the defalut ItemPanel  template of GridView, which is also VirtualizingStackPanel. I have updated my answer, please check it.

Answer (score 0):

Use `x:Key`, not `x:Name`, like

```
<Style TargetType="ListView" x:Key="ListStyle">
```

Usually we use key to find the user defined styles, not name.

Comment: Thank you but that does not fix the crash.